# BootUp broadcast not working? Android Emulator vs Real Devices. Testing an app on both

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an android app for data analysis built in java.
Our app's functionalities needs our app to restart every time the device boots up.
So I learnt about broadcasts and broadcast receivers.
And I've implemented a broadcast receiver which looks like this:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String TAG = "BootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Boot receiver received.");
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Package name is: "+ packageName);
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class);
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

I've also added permissions and receiver in androidmanifest.xml like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<application>...
       <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

So I tried to run this app on Android TV emulator device version 11 and 10. The app as expected restarted when the emulator reboots. But the issue is when I tried the same apk with real/physical android mobile device version 11 it didn't restarted and as it can be seen that I've added some logs for debugging in my BootReceiver broadcast receiver. These alsa can't be seen in logcat of android studio in case of my android mobile device.

So I am bit confused is there any difference in emulators and real devices or am I completely searching in the wrong direction?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: have you checked if your app is not falling into  "Battery optimized" settings or anything that physical device you test on does? Also, have you tried on another real device, best from different vendor (so different version of Android)?